# Do Samesite cookies changes effects sessionStorage too?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, session-storage, samesite

I'm using sessionStorage at some places in my application.

Since last few days, I've noticed that sessionStorage becoming null if I read it after API call.

Is this is because of Chrome Update? If yes, Please let me know how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sessionStorage` is not affected by the `SameSite` attribute changes for cookies.